Is it possible to use HTML/JavaScript to write form data into a .TXT file on my hard drive without servers?
I have a HTML website with a form on it that requires users to input their email address. I want the user's response to be saved to a plain text file on my hard drive. The complication is that I don't have web servers, which makes it difficult to do this. When I've tried to do this before, it just links the user to the empty text file.
I tried putting the name of the .txt as the form's action, and it just linked me to the file, giving me a blank screen.

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?

Well, you certainly do have a web server, unless users need to come to your desk and use your computer to fill the form. I guess you mean you don't have a server-side language to process requests. If you can only serve static HTML, then the answer is no, you cannot create files. Can you give some more context? Hosting may not be free (not at least if you want something reliable) but it can be really affordable.

I presume it is on a web server where you can't run scripts? Then you could try a service like Amazon AWS, Microsoft Azure or Google Cloud. The data would be send to this service and not directly to your hard drive.
You could also look into sending a request to a emailing service like sendgrid which could send the data to you via email. The data would be send to your email provider (and not directly to your hard drive).
